# Storing data in a struct or txt file?

Tags: c, struct, account

Im making an mock ATM program for practice and was wondering is it better
to

1. store someones account information in a struct on another file and have each users information on that
2. Have it all in a txt file and just read it while making an algorithm to grab what you need based on pin location ?

right now iv just made a pin list in a text file which counts and stores the data into an array which i check which then opens an account based on that user input ect ect.

i can see both working but was just wondering whats the proper process for stuff such as this ?

Comment: Depends on use case. Does the data need to persist between program executions? If it does (and doesn't need to be encrypted) I would consider storing it in a standardized format, like JSON, CSV, or XML. Also, what is a 'pin list'?

Comment: If you're practicing, try both approaches and see what works best. Apart from that, this question is kind of unclear because the problem statement assumes readers are aware of how your program works, while they really are not because of missing context.

Comment: Oh sorry i probably should of reworded the question to 
whats the most efficient/ quickest way to store/modify and read data for c language in terms for a user account.

But i do think it would be a good learning opportunity to do both

@spline, il check those out and see if theyre a better alternative

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It may depend on your operating system and the language/development tools you use as some will have libraries allowing easy access to structured data in a standardized format as pointed out above.
Text files are rarely the way to go long term since you will have to write all the code yourself, not only creating a lot of work but opening yourself to bugs and potential security issues. If you can use a library, a lot of that work is already done for you.

Comment: oh ok, il steer clear of txt files then. il look into what  Reticulated Spline mentioned then.